# What does this APWA marking mean?

Tags: safety, digging

A company needs to dig in my back yard, so they arranged the various utilities to mark the area.

One utility left this in yellow spray paint on the yard:

```
 / \
/ | \
  |
  |
NO
NM60.
```

I am located in New Mexico, so assume NM might refer to the state.

Any idea what the marking means?

Comment: At least in my area (New York), markings in yellow relate to gas lines.

Comment: @crip659 “No” means “no conflict” not “no digging” .

Comment: @LeeSam  Thanks for the proper information.

Answer (score 3):

"No conflict", with NM60 being the facility doing the marking.

> When there is “no conflict” between buried utilities and the proposed area of excavation, locators will mark “NO” oftentimes followed by the name of the facility, or the abbreviated facility type with a line drawn through it.
>
> http://www.gopherstateonecall.org/news-events/688-locator-language-decoding-utility-markings

See http://www2.apwa.net/documents/about/techsvcs/one-call/final_marking_report.pdf for more markings.

Comment: Yeah, the fact it's yellow tells us that NM60 would be a code for a gas utility (likely the OP's local gas utility, even)